# \newline in moderncv(\cvlanguage)

Tags: line-breaking, moderncv

I would like to have a newline inside of a \cvlanguage environment. I did it before with no problem but now it doesn't work (I have changed from casual to classic in the cvtheme, I don't know if it is related).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\firstname{John }
\familyname{Doe}
\mobile{    6666666666      }                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin][es.linkedin.com/in/johndoe]{John Doe}
\email{johndoe@gmail.com         }                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Idiomas}
\cvlanguage{Ingl\'es}{Alto. Nivel: C2* \newline  \footnotesize{T\'itulo superior de ingl\'es. Escuela Oficial de Idiomas de Alicante  2000-2005.}}{}
\cvlanguage{Catal\'an}{Alto. Nivel: C2* \newline  \footnotesize{T\'itulo Mitj\`a de Valenci\`a. Junta Qualificadora de Coneixements de Valenci\`a 2004.}}{}
\cvlanguage{Alem\'an}{Intermedio. Nivel: B2* \newline  \footnotesize{T\'itulo Intermedio de Alem\'an. Escuela Oficial de Idiomas de Alicante 2009.}}{}
\cvlanguage{Franc\'es}{Pre-intermedio. Nivel: A2* \newline \footnotesize{Escuela Oficial de Idiomas de Madrid 2017.} 
\newline \newline\emph{*Common European Framework of Reference(CEF) level.}}{}
\end{document}
```

Regards,

Ignacio

Comment: Please, make a minimal but complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. No need to give the full data in the top part of the CV, just ensure the document shows the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new command that allows the second argument to be split across lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\cvlanguagesplit}[3]{%
  \cvlanguage{#1}{\parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{#2}}{#3}%
}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\mobile{6666666666}
\social[linkedin][es.linkedin.com/in/johndoe]{John Doe}
\email{johndoe@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Idiomas}
\cvlanguagesplit{Ingl\'es}{%
  Alto. Nivel: C2* \\
  \footnotesize T\'itulo superior de ingl\'es. 
  Escuela Oficial de Idiomas de Alicante  2000-2005.%
}{}
\cvlanguagesplit{Catal\'an}{%
  Alto. Nivel: C2* \\
  \footnotesize T\'itulo Mitj\`a de Valenci\`a. 
  Junta Qualificadora de Coneixements de Valenci\`a 2004.%
}{}
\cvlanguagesplit{Alem\'an}{%
  Intermedio. Nivel: B2* \\
  \footnotesize T\'itulo Intermedio de Alem\'an. 
  Escuela Oficial de Idiomas de Alicante 2009.%
}{}
\cvlanguagesplit{Franc\'es}{%
  Pre-intermedio. Nivel: A2* \\
  \footnotesize Escuela Oficial de Idiomas de Madrid 2017. 
  \emph{*Common European Framework of Reference(CEF) level.}%
}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a not-really-smart-solution but it works.

Just in case someone is interested: similar results can be obtained with the \cventry command and there the \newline command works well (actually you will find a new issue of removing extra dots, but it can easily remove with some help found in this web).